# Genie Vala Generics and Nullable Types

Tags: gtk3, gnome, vala, genie

Simple question: In the following generic class, how should the generic type and contained types be defined so that they are nullable?  The following will not compile.

```
class Pair? of G1, G2: Object

    _first:G1?
    _second:G2?

    construct()

        _first = null
        _second = null

    def insert( first:G1, second:G2 )

        _first = first
        _second = second

    def insert_first( value:G1 )

        _first = value

    def insert_second( value:G2 )

        _second = value

    def second():G2

        return _second
```

Usage:

```
var pair = new Pair() of string, string
pair = null
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Due to the way Vala Generics work, generic parameters are always nullable.

As long as you don't switch on `--enable-experimental-non-null` class variables are nullable as well, so your code simplifies to:

```
[indent=4]
class Pair of G1, G2: Object

    _first:G1
    _second:G2

    construct()

        _first = null
        _second = null

    def insert( first:G1, second:G2 )

        _first = first
        _second = second

    def insert_first( value:G1 )

        _first = value

    def insert_second( value:G2 )

        _second = value

    def second():G2

        return _second

init
    var pair = new Pair of string, string
    pair = null
```

When `--enable-experimental-non-null` is on, you have to be explicit in the type of the variable. I don't know how to write this in Genie, I tried this, but the compiler does not like it:

```
init
    pair: Pair? of string, string = new Pair of string, string
    pair = null
```

In Vala it's no problem:

```
class Pair<G1,G2>: Object {
    private G1 first;
    private G2 second;

    public Pair () {
        first = null;
        second = null;
    }

    // ...
}

int main () {
    Pair<string, string>? pair = new Pair<string, string> ();
    pair = null;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Generic parameters being always nullable is a great feature.  I'm approaching this from a C++ template (Alexandrescu) background.  Pair<T1,T2> is a foundational generic element in C++ and I wanted to see how Genie/Vala would look by comparison.  Of course they are entirely different - C++ is compile time and Vala/Genie is run time, as I understand it.

Comment: Hmm, I would take that with a pinch of salt. Pair<null, null> is not valid. If you really want to bypass that then you can use Pair<void*, void*>. The Vala compiler uses a pointer based generics system so void* is a null pointer, but that's really only useful for C bindings at best. Assigning null to the field _first:G1 should be a compile time error to my mind. Doing that with _first:int, _first:string or _first:My_Class are all compile time errors. Type parameters are statically checked at compile time, but they have runtime type information passed using GType unless simple_generics=true

Comment: The final code sample in this answer should not compile with --enable-experimental-non-null. This is a bug in the the non-null checker when a null assignment occurs in a constructor. Please see [bug 793912](https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=793912) for details. It is an over-generalisation from this bug to state "generic parameters are always nullable".

Comment: True, Vala Generics are a bit quirky. I was writing more from a pratical standpoint than from a language lawyer one here.

Comment: I'm sorry I don't follow the meaning of your comment. Your code identified a bug in the Vala compiler and I took the time to report that. The bug is an inconsistency in the way generic types are handled when compared to other types - so the quirk is a bug to my mind. Do you not agree? By making things consistent it is more obvious to the practical programmer how Vala works, so you don't have to be a "language lawyer" digging through pages of documentation to find the quirk is actually a feature :) You could just edit your answer and add the '?' in the right places in the example.

Comment: Well, there is not a rigorous standard document for Vala (as there is for example for C++) anyway. To the point: I'd like it to be consistent, but you have to think of how Vala Generics work. A generic GLib type implemented in C (take GLib.List<G> as an example) has `gpointer` as its generic parameter data type. `gpointer` already implicitly contains the possibility to contain a NULL value. So what you are asking for would only be possible in "pure" Vala code. There are trade-offs that have to be made in language interop.

Answer (score 2):

I can't wrap my head around the concept of a type parameter that has null as the type. I don't think that is a useful concept. So the definition of your class would be:

```
[indent = 4]
class Pair of G1, G2: Object

    _first:G1?
    _second:G2?

    def insert( first:G1, second:G2 )
        _first = first
        _second = second

    def insert_first( value:G1 )
        _first = value

    def insert_second( value:G2 )
        _second = value

    def second():G2
        return _second
```

If you must re-assign the variable that has the object instance to null then it would be:

```
[indent = 4]
init
    var pair = new Pair of string,string()
    pair = null
```

The Vala compiler will, however, dereference `pair` when it goes out of scope. So I'm not sure why you would need to assign null.

The use of nulls would ideally only be used when interfacing with a C library in my view. Accessing a null can lead to a crash (segmentation fault) if it is not checked for properly. For example:

```
init
    a:int? = 1
    a = null
    var b = a + 1
```

The Vala compiler does have an experimental non-null mode that does some checking for unsafe code. If you compile the following with the Vala switch `--enable-experimental-non-null`:

```
[indent = 4]
init
    var pair = new Pair of string,string()
    pair = null
```

you will get the error:

`error: Assignment: Cannot convert from`null' to `Pair<string,string>'`

If you understand the consequences then you can tell the compiler this is OK with:

```
[indent = 4]
init
    pair:Pair? = new Pair of string,string()
    pair = null
```

Comment: My interest in the use of null assignment is to make runtime initialization / testing / raising exceptions more type independent - if that makes sense.

Comment: Genie is a strongly typed language. I would interpret "more type independent" as either trying to bypass the type system or a synonym for polymorphism. If you are are tying to bypass the type system then you need to re-think your approach. This could lead to an interesting set of Stack Overflow questions and I would try and feed that back in to the Genie tutorial. If you want polymorphism then interfaces are very useful. You can also have runtime dynamic types with the use of GValue if you really need them, e.g. Value a = 10. This is useful for a library to be used by Python, etc.

Comment: My thinking is not so foundational - its simply having the ability to do something like:  `if pair == null raise Error( " ... " )`.  Knowing that Generic parameters are always nullable is useful in this respect - my intention was not to bypass the type system.

Comment: OK, but be aware there is on going work on the Vala compiler to make the use of nulls explicit with static analysis using --enable-experimental-non-null. The aim being to avoid having to pepper your code with null checks unless explicitly required to.

Comment: Thanks.  For C++, throwing an exception from a constructor can lead to undefined behaviour; what is the result if this happens within Vala/Genie?

Comment: It is fine. An exception is implemented as a GError. This is an out parameter in the C code for the constructor. See the new IOChannel.file example in [Error Handling](https://wiki.gnome.org/Projects/Vala/Tutorial#Error_Handling) section of the Vala tutorial.